# What is the best way to allow canceling of a modal form when there is field level validation?

Tags: delphi, validation

What is the best way to allow canceling of a modal form when there is field level validation?

I have a Delphi form shown modally.  In it there are TComboBoxes, TEdits, an Ok and Cancel buttons.  These fields have OnExit methods the fire to check that the data is valid.  However, I would like to have the Cancel button click allow the form to close without validating the fields.  What happens is when the Cancel button is clicked, then the OnExit of the field is called and validation is run before the OnClick of the button which closes the form.  This timing is undesirable because it causes the user to correct data that they wish to abandon.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I abandoned data validation "on field exit" altogether.  It frustrates users who know what they're doing (for example, someone may be copying data from another source and pasting on the current screen, in a way that will only make sense only when all data is pasted in--validation per field usually gets on the way of such actions).

Instead, try performing data validation when the user is ready to move on from the current screen, usually when they click the "OK" or "Next" button.

Comment: Validation doesn't always mean to be a nerdy message dialog screaming something about wrong data. It can also be e.g. a red colored input field text, some sort of exclamation mark icon beside the field or e.g. a warning bubble that pops up from the field. In all cases it will prevent user to save the record of course.

Comment: TLama--you're right, as long as the OnExit event doesn't lock the user in until the data is corrected.

Comment: I like the idea of avoiding the whole problem as suggested by @user1595471 and will propose changing our error checking framework to allow this, or at least changing how the error is shown to the user as per TLama.  However, if this is deemed unacceptable then I will look for other options.  My first thought is passing a user defined message to myself requesting the field checked.  I believe this will allow the cancel button's event to fire and close the form before the user defined message is handled.  Thanks all for the input.

Comment: @user1627960: Nilling all controls' OnExit handlers in the Cancel button's OnClick handler would be the simplest and possibly cleanest approach, but requires form's always being instantiated and not re-shown, or hooking them back up in an OnActivate or OnShow... (the old values could be saved before nilling)

Comment: @Marjan: the problem is that the OnExit event fires before the button's OnClick event.